# How do I switch back to using Modern IE instead of Desktop IE?

Tags: windows-8, modern-ui, internet-explorer-11

Like many, when I first got Windows 8.1 I thought I would not like the new version of IE (Modern IE), so I switched to using Desktop IE (Classic UI) exclusively. Now I want to undo my mistake. Trouble is, all I can find are extremely complex steps to remedy this. Isn't there some straightforward way to switch back to Modern IE?

Comment: You can Reset IE if you want.  But honestly I have no idea what you mean by "classic view" so how about be specific and link to what your talkinga about because its not that common.

Comment: If you mean use the desktop version of of IE11, just launch the desktop version, instead of the Modern UI IE.

Comment: When I got my new Surface 3, if you opened IE the browser opens with tabs at the bottom.Right click and a bar at the bottom lets you pin websites to Start screen. However if you choose the Classic IE, the tabs go to the top as Windows 7- no pinning. If you do that and decide you want the new user interface, I cannot find a way to reverse the action. Relaunching the desktop version does not work. Once you've switched, any time you launch IE it comes out looking like you're in the old forms of IE and Windows 7. I want the new user interface back. There's got to be someone out there like me.

Comment: I have a surface pro 3, just launch the desktop version of IE11 from the desktop or use the "switch to desktop option" in the modern IE application hamburger button

Comment: @Ramhound: OP says "I want the new user interface back", so you're consistently telling him how to switch to Desktop IE when clearly he wants to do the exact opposite i.e. use Metro IE.

Answer (score 1):

To switch from Desktop IE ("Classic UI") to Modern IE:

1. Open Desktop IE, click the *Settings* (Gear) icon on the top right side and select *Internet Options*.
2. On the *Programs* tab, under the *Opening Internet Explorer* section if you see a *Make Internet Explorer the default browser* link then click it, otherwise go to step 4:

   [image: 1]
3. This will open the *Set Default Programs* dialog. Select Internet Explorer in the Programs list, click the *Set this program as default* button and OK your way out:

   [image: 2]
4. OK your way out of the *Internet Options* dialog and close IE, then open it again and go to the same *Programs* tab. This time under the *Opening Internet Explorer* section make sure *Let Internet Explorer decide* is selected and and especially *Open Internet Explorer tiles on the desktop* is unchecked:

   [image: 3]
5. OK your way out of the *Internet Options* dialog and close IE, then click the Modern IE tile on the Start Screen to launch it:

   [image: 4]

   Here's the Desktop IE tile in comparison:

   [image: 5]